# What is the airfoil used in the SB13 flying wing?

Tags: aircraft-design, airfoil, flying-wing

[image]
([Source](http://www.rc-network.de/forum/showthread.php/11845-Mini-SB13-von-Graupner?s=d11654340babd9f0a07cf682281c3fc5))

What airfoil is used for the wing of this aircraft?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Wikipedia Page on [SB-13 Arcus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaflieg_Braunschweig_SB-13_Arcus), the airfoil used are,

> HQ 34N/14.83 at root, HQ 36N/15.12 at tip. Winglet Wortmann FX 7-L-150/K30